# I want to concatenate these two objects to get the following result $scope.all=[ lead value and contact value]

Tags: angularjs

```
$scope.lead = [
              {name: 'raj', email:'raj@gmail.com'}

            ];
$scope.contact=[
                {name: 'James', email:'james@gmail.com'}

                ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like more related to JS than angular itself.

```
$scope.lead = [{name: 'raj', email:'raj@gmail.com'}];
$scope.contact =[{name: 'James', email:'james@gmail.com'}];

$scope.all = {};

$scope.all.lead = $scope.lead;
$scope.all.contact = $scope.contact;

console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.all))
```